# My else if statement is giving syntax error

Tags: javascript

```
window.setInterval(function(){


var value = $("#pizzaNumber").val();

if (value=0) {

document.getElementById('type2').style.display = 'none';

document.getElementById('type3').style.display = 'none';

{


else if (value=2) {

document.getElementById('type2').style.display = 'block';

}

else if (value=3) {


document.getElementById('type2').style.display = 'block';

document.getElementById('type3').style.display = 'block';

}

else {

document.getElementById('type2').style.display = 'none';

document.getElementById('type3').style.display = 'none';

alert("Invaild Number Entered");

}

}, 2000);
```

Comment: Next time indent your code. Makes spotting structural errors way easier.

Comment: Yes, please provide the error you are getting so that finding the error is less cumbersome. And indenting your code would nice. Hope that's not too much to ask!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first if statement is closed by a `{` instead of a `}`. That's what's causing your syntax error. However, as David said, you should be comparing using `==` or ideally `===` instead of `=`. A single `=` is assignment, not comparison.

Comment: thank you that solved it somehow i didnt catch that

Answer (score 2):

When comparing numbers use the `===` operator. Not the assignment operator `=`.

```
 if ( a === b )
```

Moreoever, you're missing an ending bracket to your first if statement.

Comment: True but not the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

End your first if block with a *closing* brace:

```
if (foo) {

}
```

Also, don't assign in conditionals:

```
if (value === 0) // not if (value = 0)
```

Comment: what do you mean dont assign conditionals please explain im very new at javascript

Comment: whats the difference between = == and ===

Comment: `if (value = 0)` sets "value" to 0 and returns 0 which is construed as false.  `if (value == 0)` tests if value is 0, null, undefined, empty string, false and returns true if any of those conditions is met.  `if (value === 0)` returns true only if value is zero.